# Torch7 : No batchNorm or Dropout, but model:training() and model:evaluate() produce different results

Tags: machine-learning, torch

I have trained a small network which is basically a `torch.ParallelTable` with two branches, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The **Net1** and **Net2** parts are just composed of standard `nn.SpatialConvolution`, `nn.SpatialFullConvolution`, `nn.SpatialMaxPooling` and `nn.PRelu`. So nothing unusual. The **SPP** 
part is a `inn.SpatialPyramidalPooling` layer from the [inn](https://github.com/szagoruyko/imagine-nn) package. 
I haven't used any batch normalization or droptout. I've trained the network with a `nn.MSECriterion` as the loss, and the error is of the order of `10^{-11}`, so it seems that it overfits. However, when forwarding in `evaluate()` mode, I get an error of about `0.5`...

```
model:training()
res=model:forward(some_data)
loss=my_loss:forward(res,some_ground_truth)  -- about 10^{-11}
```

But if I change to evaluation mode I get

```
model:evaluate()
res=model:forward(some_data)
loss=my_loss:forward(res,some_ground_truth)  -- about 0.5
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening?